# ambiguous mapping while deploying

Tags: java, git, tomcat, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 1.6.20 ([Git Client Plugin 1.18.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin), [Git Plugin 2.4.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)) to get the Java application code from bitbucket.org and deploy it to Apache Tomcat 8.0.23.

The error appears while deploying and looks like:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/spr$
>   public java.util.List by.ipps.accounting.ws.PositionWS.getEmployeePost(java.lang.Long)
>   to {[/positionListJson/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'resourceWS' bean method
>   public by.ipps.accounting.model.Employee.EmployeePost by.ipps.accounting.ws.ResourceWS.getEmployeePost(java.lang.Long) mapped.
>
> bla-bla-bla ... so many errors ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'positionWS' bean method
>   public java.util.List by.ipps.accounting.ws.PositionWS.getEmployeePost(java.lang.Long)
>   to {[/positionListJson/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'resourceWS' bean method
>   public by.ipps.accounting.model.Employee.EmployeePost by.ipps.accounting.ws.ResourceWS.getEmployeePost(java.lang.Long) mapped.

The problem is that the class (with annotation @Controller) **PositionWS** with method getEmployeePost was renamed to **ResourceWS** a week ago, so exists no more, so I should not get this error.

To fix this I have to create a blank PositionWS controller (with no methods in it), commit & push that to bitbucket (and delete (cus i really don't need it) later and commit & push).

It seems to be like a bug in any of the applications I use. **I can't find out in which app there is a bug to report it.** Tell me please, if anyone faced such problems.

Comment: Have you simply tried wiping the workspace in Jenkins? Or checking your jenkins path for the class? It seems like there's either a cached version somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of the issue was in incorrect configuration of Jenkins, it was my fault.

When I was configuring Jenkins I set maven goal as "install", but it must be "***clean install***". According to this Jenkins never deleted old files and kept them, so got a lot of issues of different kinds and with different log messages.
Due to Jenkins working specialty it downloads project files and try to assemble it on path `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<projectName>/workspace/target/`.

So I've drop the data in this folder and afterwards set maven goal to "clean install" and that fixed the issue.